# Terraform: Add item to a DynamoDB Table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, terraform

What is the correct way to add tuple and key-pair values items to a DynamoDB database via Terraform?

I am trying like this:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "item" {
    table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.dynamodb-table.name
    hash_key = aws_dynamodb_table.dynamodb-table.hash_key

    for_each = {
        "0" = {
            location = "Madrid"
            coordinates = [["lat", "40.49"], ["lng", "-3.56"]]
            visible = false
            destinations = [0, 4]
        }
    }

    item = <<ITEM
    {
        "id": { "N": "${each.key}"},
        "location": {"S" : "${each.value.location}"},
        "visible": {"B" : "${each.value.visible}"},
        "destinations": {"L" : [{"N": "${each.value.destinations}"}]
    }
    ITEM
}
```

And I am getting the message:

each.value.destinations is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

I also have no clue on how to add the coordinates variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"destinations": {"NS": ${jsonencode(each.value.destinations)}}
```

Did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

List should be something like that :

```
"destinations": {"L": [{ "N" : 1 }, { "N" : 2 }]}
```

You are trying to pass

```
"destinations": {"L": [{ "N" : [0,4] }]}
```

Also you are missing the last } in destinations key

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: I think the problem here is that you are trying to put `L(N)` - i.e. a list of numeric values, while your current Terraform code tries to put all the destinations into one `N`/number.

Instead of:

```
[{"N": "${each.value.destinations}"}]
```

you need some iteration over destinations and building a `{"N": ...}` of them.